# Connecting a Lightsail instance of WordPress to a Lightsail MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-lightsail

This is my first go at AWS. I’m trying to install a WordPress site. Here’s what I’ve done so far:

Created a LAMP instance in Lightsail. I’m able to:

- SSH into the webroot with Terminal
- SFTP into the webroot with Filezilla
- Successfully uploaded and expanded the latest version of WP
  in the webroot
- Using the public IP, accessed the WP setup screen

Created an instance of a MySQL database in Lightsail. I’m able to:

- Use Terminal to tunnel into and access it in the browser with
  PHPMyAdmin
- Successfully create an empty database and user with full
  access permissions

Additionally:

- Both instances are running in the same region: Virginia, Zone A
  (us-east-1a)
- I have enabled both Data migration and Public Mode

At the WordPress setup screen I enter the database name, user, password and host. I believe the database host is what the instance calls the endpoint? After all that, I get the following error:

```
We were able to connect to the database server (which means your username
and password is okay) but not able to select the publicUser database.
```

I’m quite sure the required credentials are correct, so it must be something with how I’m doing the setup? Any ideas? **If anyone has this same setup, can you please post your WordPress config file with the sensitive information removed so I can see how you're connecting?**

Answer (score 0):

You've done everything correctly so far. WordPress is now looking for a database with the name `publicUser` which it cannot find. You either did not create that database (via PHPMyAdmin) yet, or are using the wrong database name.

Once you have either created the database or corrected the configured database name, it should work.

Comment: Creating the database is the first thing I did. It's actually `publicuser`, not `publicUser`, my apologies. I'm still getting the same error. I don't understand this, it can login to the database server, but not find the database? If it were a problem with permissions, I would expect WP to say that. The database is there, that's 100%. This is very odd.

Comment: Make sure the database name configured matches exactly with how its created within MySQL itself. You can also try to use the MySQL command line client via SSH on your Lightsail instance WordPress is running on. Login to that database with the same exact settings WordPress uses (username, password, host and database name). If that works, it should work for WordPress too.

Comment: There's no doubt the database name is correct and present. Below the error are some hints. The first one is about the database existence, so that's out. The second  says:`Does the user dbmasteruser have permission to use the publicuser database?`

I assumed that's a yes unless AWS works different that I think.

Comment: Considering your comment `Successfully create an empty database and user with full access permissions`, it should be fine. You can test this by doing what I proposed in my comment, using the MySQL client on the Lightsail instance on which WordPress runs. Connect to the database using the same information WordPress uses, something like `mysql -u dbmasteruser -p -h database.host.amazonaws.com publicuser` where `publicuser` is the database name. If this works, then the problem is within WordPress and not so much in AWS.

Comment: "the MySQL client on the Lightsail instance on which WordPress runs"? I'm using PHPMyAdmin via an SSH tunnel. But, here's what the database log says:

`611 Connect dbmasteruser@000.00.00.00 on using TCP/IP
611 Query SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode
611 Query SET SESSION sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
611 Query SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode
611 Query SET SESSION sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
611 Quit `

Comment: If someone is running an instance of WP in Lightsail that accesses a MySQL database in Lightsail, I'd appreciate if you posted how your login information is structured?